# LINQ - many to many

Tags: linq, many-to-many

I have 2 collections - **invitedUserAllowedTimes** and **meeting.AllowedTimes**. Collection **invitedUserAllowedTimes** has collection **invitedUserAllowedTimes.Times**.

Collection **invitedUserAllowedTimes.Times** has values TimeID = 1, TimeID = 2, TimeID = 3, TimeID = 4, TimeID = 5, TimeID = 6.

Collection **meeting.AllowedTimes** has values TimeID = 2, TimeID = 3, TimeID = 4.

I want to select from **invitedUserAllowedTimes** all records, which has all **meeting.AllowedTimes** TimeIDs.
I try to do following:

```
var times = (
    from i in invitedUserAllowedTimes 
    where i.Times.All(p => meeting.AllowedTimes.Any(k=>k.TimeID == p.TimeID))
    select i).ToList();
```

but get no records. Why? What is incorrect in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not returning anything because you're asking it to return all `invitedUserAllowedTimes` where **all** of its times are in `meeting.AllowedTimes`. So your example won't return it because `meeting.AllowedTimes` doesn't have TimeID 1, 5, or 6.

Instead you need to do this:

```
var times = (
    from i in invitedUserAllowedTimes 
    where meeting.AllowedTimes.All(k=> i.Times.Contains(k.TimeID))
    select i).ToList();
```

Or, using extension methods:

```
var times = invitedUserAllowedTimes.Where(i => meeting.AllowedTimes.All(k => i.Times.Contains(k.TimeID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var times = (from i in invitedUserAllowedTimes 
             where meeting.AllowedTimes.All(k => i.Times.Contains(k.TimeID))
             select i).ToList();
```